# ㄹ 거에요 vs. ㄹ 거예요 - are both correct? If so, do they mean different things?

Tags: grammar

http://www.koreanlanguagenerd.com/grammarindex/vs1 suggests that both ㄹ 거에요 and ㄹ 거예요 can be correct, and have slightly different meanings - it states that:

> The main difference is that the future tense uses 거에요. 
>   As in 저는 할 거에요. I will do it.

and gives examples:

> 네일은 추울거에요. Tomorrow will be cold. 
>   추울 거예요. It might be cold.

However, I don't really understand the explanation, and other sources (e.g. https://www.italki.com/question/301014?hl=ko) seem to say that 거예요 is correct, as it's a contraction of ㄹ 것 이에요. That makes more sense to me...

are both ㄹ 거에요 and ㄹ 거예요 correct? If so, do they mean different things as suggested in the koreanlanguagenerd article?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding `ㄹ` before a noun...that does give it a future tense.  So in short, they are both equal in their future tense and the noun that is modified into a future tense is `것`, also abbreviated here.

The real ponderance is [~에요 vs 예요](https://namu.wiki/w/~%EC%97%90%EC%9A%94%EC%99%80%20%EC%98%88%EC%9A%94%EC%9D%98%20%EA%B5%AC%EB%B6%84), and I'm going to quite happily do a potentially errant job of translating the important parts of that page:

> '예요'는 '이에요'를 줄인 형태이다. 서술격조사 '이-'가 붙는 말 뒤에는 '-에요', 아니면 '예요'가 온다. 동사나 형용사도 '-에요'가 온다.

*`예요` is `이에요`, just in abbreviated form.  What is happening here is that after `이` either `에요` or `이에요` is suffixed.  In the case of both action verbs and descriptive verbs `에요` is the result.*

The page goes on to show three types of usage pattern:

> 받침이 있는 명사 뒤에서: '이에요'를 쓴다. 줄어든 형태 '예요'를 쓰면 틀림. (예: 책상이다 ➡ 책상이에요.)

*With syllables that end in a consonant, use `이에요`. It is incorrect to abbreviate to `예요`.*

*(Example: 책상이다 ➡ 책상이에요)*

> 받침이 없는 명사 뒤에서 '예요'를 쓴다. 줄지 않은 '이에요'를 쓰면 틀림. (예: 의자다 ➡ 의자예요.)

*With syllables that do not end in a consonant, use `예요`.
It is incorrect to use `이에요`.*

*(Example: 의자다 ➡ 의자예요)*

> 동사나 형용사 뒤에서: '-에요'를 쓴다. (예 : 아니다 ➡ 아니에요.)

*Following a verb (action or descriptive) use `에요`.*

*(Example: 아니다 ➡ 아니에요)*

**So in the case of**

> 뭔가를 할것이다

We have a noun that ends in a consonant: `뭔가를 할 것 이에요`.

**But in the abbreviated `것` as `거`**

> 뭔가를 할거다 (awkward, no?)

Our noun has no consonant: `뭔가를 할 거예요`.

**Answer [(and source)](https://namu.wiki/w/~%EC%97%90%EC%9A%94%EC%99%80%20%EC%98%88%EC%9A%94%EC%9D%98%20%EA%B5%AC%EB%B6%84)**

-ㄹ 거에요 is incorrect.

-ㄹ 거예요 is correct because the noun `거` has no 받침.

Comment: Nice background, but this doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Comment: i'll clarify then

Comment: +1 This is a very good answer. Even native Korean speakers often don't know when to use `에요` and when to use `예요`.

Comment: `뭔가를 할 거다` doesn't sound awkward, and in fact is actually more commonly said than `뭔가를 할 것이다` in spoken Korean in my opinion. But it does **read** awkward, since in written Korean, people would habitually write `뭔가를 할 것이다` instead of `뭔가를 할 거다` almost all the time. This is just my opinion though.

Comment: @jeonghyeonlee Agreed on writing 할 것이다 and saying 할 거다 - that helps me understand the oddness i was feeling as i wrote that, but then how fluid it sounds when i say `할 거다` - and thank you for the compliment, though the glory [belongs to namu.wiki](https://namu.wiki/w/~%EC%97%90%EC%9A%94%EC%99%80%20%EC%98%88%EC%9A%94%EC%9D%98%20%EA%B5%AC%EB%B6%84)